# Google Drive API v2 - list all files that label/restricted = false

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

My question is simple and described in the Title.

I would like to write a script in App Script, that will search and list all the files in my Drive (Folders and Subfolders) that labels/restricted is false.

I could fetch all files and check one by one, but this is very time consuming script.

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

To be more specific I use the Script Editor in a Google Spreadsheet. 
I have enabled the Drive API in Script Editor in case I need it.

A simple search I use to find files that the modified date in one hour ago is the following:

```
var today     = new Date(); 
var oneHourAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - 1 * 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var startTime = oneHourAgo.toISOString();
var search = '(trashed = true or trashed = false) and (modifiedDate > "' + startTime + '")';
var files  = DriveApp.searchFiles(search);
```

Now, I would like to search all the files in Drive that has the property label.restricted equals false.

Comment: What have you tried? There are similar questions that could get you most of the way there: [How to list all files (or only certains type of files) inside a main folder and all its subfolders in Google Drive using GAS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841016), [List all files in a folder, including files in sub folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750101/), and others. Further, it's not clear what technology you're asking about; Google Apps Script and the Google Drive API are not the same thing.

Comment: This might help: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String)

Comment: I updated my post to be more specific.

Comment: cannot check now but looking at your update I think that this can a way to go: `DriveApp.searchFiles("properties has { key='label.restricted' and value='false' }");`

Comment: Below script does not work: (error: invalid query)
`DriveApp.searchFiles("properties has { key='label.restricted' and value='false' }");`

Comment: @LoukasNikolaidis it should be DriveApp.searchFiles('properties has { key="label.restricted" and value = "false" and visibility="PRIVATE" }')
I thought it could go without the last parameter but it actually can't.
More detailedly https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String) and https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in Apps Script if you use the [Advanced Drive Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive).

> The advanced Drive service allows you to use the [Google Drive web API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/) in Apps Script. Much like Apps Script's [built-in Drive service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive), this API allows scripts to create, find, and modify files and folders in Google Drive.

```
Drive.Files.list({'labels': {'restricted': true}}, fileId);
```

Be noted that this must be [enabled before use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced).

Comment: Hi, this script does not work for what I want to do. 
Giving the fileId it is like asking to get info for a single file.