# continuationToken, how to use

Tags: google-apps-script

As from GAS References, we take terrific pleasure of the following method:
[image]

It is - or better it sounds - extremely useful, in case the script exceeds the time limit granted by quotas.
But, but, but:

- **"resume" from where**? Which in other words means
- **where are tokens**, that "are generally valid for one week", **stored**? Which would lead to the subsequent question
- **how to recall the continuationToken string** to use as parameter of DriveApp.continueFolderIterator()?

---

I am aware of the possibility to use User Properties, as suggested elsewhere, but I would avoid to play such solution since User Properties have a more general purpose.

Comment: related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689629/how-to-use-continuationtoken-with-recursive-folder-iterator), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365681/correct-usage-of-driveapp-continuefileiteratorcontinuationtoken), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052473/folder-iterator-continuation-token-recursive-loop)

Comment: I knew (and appreciated) the several solutions proposed with the links submitted by @Kos (Script Properties section is greatly effective for such purpose) but I expect to use the continuationToken in a script different from the one where the continuationToken was got.

Comment: First i would check if it is even possible to run it in another script. Maybe it is bound because of reasons like auth? Simple test would suffice right?

Comment: Hi @RemcoE33, good for you today on bycicle. I found out a solution, and it works: the script calculates elapsed time and on passing the time limit it gets the continuationToken string generated by FolderIterator method. Then the script saves such string in a cell of a specific spreadsheet I created as a sort of "Developer Properties". Then, any different script can recover from the spreadsheet the continuationToken string to be used as argument of the DriveApp methods useful to resume a folder/files iteration. It works, I do not know how and why, but works.