# Max execution work-around Google App Script

Tags: directory, execution-time

I'm looking to retrieve the entire folder/subfolder directory from MyDrive and print out to a file type (not sure what' possible).  I ran the following code and received a "max execution timeout" error.

```
// Log the name of every folder in the user's Drive.
var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
while (folders.hasNext()) {
var folder = folders.next();
Logger.log(folder.getName());
}
```

MyDrive contains over 20,000 files, not sure on the folder/sub-folder count.  I'm assuming the above code is meant as a starting point and not the actual full script.

Any help would be appreciated to help me get around this issue.  I only need to run the script once.

Thanks,
Ryan.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct usage of DriveApp.continueFileIterator(continuationToken)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365681/correct-usage-of-driveapp-continuefileiteratorcontinuationtoken)

Comment: I remember seeing one that also dealt with folders but the other one i just linked also covers it. Google it as its a common question answered more than once on s.o.